# If there exists a homomorphism from group $G$ onto group $H$ and a second homomorphism from $H$ onto $G$. Does this imply $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Suppose there exists an surjective homomorphism from group $G$ to group $H$ and a second surjectibehomomorphism from $H$ to $G$. Does this imply $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

I know there exists an invertible function from the set in $G$ to the set in $H$ by the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, but I am unsure if this invertible function will also be a homomorphism.

Note: I initially did not follow etiquette on edits, so I am reverting to the question that was answered in the top response. I will not do so again.

Comment: You need to explain what $G$ and $H$ are, and if by “onto” you mean surjective.

Comment: G and H are both groups and the function is surjective, as group homomorphisms are surjective. I am updating the title now.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but group homomorphisms are not necessarily surjective.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that. I must have had the definition wrong in my head. I think I can answer my question now.

Comment: Your question is still non-trivial, if you're asking about whether $G \cong H$ is implied by the existence of *surjective* group homomorphisms $G \rightarrow H$ and $H \rightarrow G$.

Comment: You are not applying Schroeder-Bernstein, you are applying its dual. Note that S-B does not require the Axiom of Choice, but [the dual implies every infinite set has a countable subset](https://mathoverflow.net/q/38771/3959), which cannot be proven in ZF.

Comment: (When you say a homomorphism is *onto* a group, people might think you mean a surjective homomorphism.)

Comment: Subject line says groups. post does not. Also, you haven't fixed the error about Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein, which is about the existence of a bijection when you have **injections** going each way.

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez:  The OP seems to ask about injections. The title of this question does not match the actual question.

Comment: It is still completely unclear what is being asked. The title suggests surjections, but the question in the body of the post is about injections. Please edit the question and make this clear.

Comment: You changed the question from surjections to injections without noting the change, making my answer seem to miss the point and possibly attracting a downvote. **Don't do that**.

Comment: @spin OP **changed** the question. If you loom at the edit history, you will see that the post originally asked about surjections (in the post, not just the subject line).

Comment: The problem wasn't your question being about surjections, the error was invoking CSB instead of invoking the **dual** (which under AC is equivalent) of CSB to conclude the existence of a bijection.

Comment: You're right. It was really late in my time zone, and I wasn't thinking that through. I will revert the question to the original and make note of the mistake in my post. Sorry about the delay on my end. I won't do it again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: Original question was about surjections, not injections. It was changed by the OP long after this answer was posted.

---

No. There exists a countable torsionfree abelian subgroup $A$ which is isomorphic to $A\times A\times A$, but not to $A\times A$. [This is a famous result of A.L.S. Corner.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10194/3959).

Let $G=A$ and $H=A\times A$. Then each has the other as a quotient (use the isomorphism of $A$ with $A\times A\times A$ to get $H$ as a quotient of $G$), but they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Maybe an easier example is given by infinite direct sums $G = C_2 \oplus C_4 \oplus C_4 \oplus \cdots$ and $H = C_4 \oplus C_4 \oplus \cdots$ These embed into each other, but are not isomorphic since not every element of order $2$ in $G$ is a square.

Comment: There are also finitely generated examples defined by Baumslag in his well-known paper on examples of nonHopfian groups.

Comment: @Spin Yes, that also works. The original post was about surjections, not injections, by the way (though your example also works for that).